NJsonSchema does not validate the data type
I enter the data type for the age property in the schema - number, but no matter how I specify it, it will still be successfully validated. what could be the problem?
My json:
{"name":"alex", "age":"14", "task":"anyTask"}

My json schema:
{"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#","type": "object","properties": {"name": {"type":"string"},"age": {"type": "number"},"task": {"type": "string"}},"required": [ "name", "age", "task" ]}

My test code:
            string shema = "{\"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\"type\": \"object\",\"properties\": {\"name\": {\"type\":\"string\"},\"age\": {\"type\": \"number\"},\"task\": {\"type\": \"string\"}},\"required\": [ \"name\", \"age\", \"task\" ]}";
            JSchema schemaWithRequiredParameters = JSchema.Parse(shema);

        [TestCase("{\"name\":\"alex\", \"age\":\"14\", \"task\":\"anyTask\"}")]
        public async Task Valid_IncompleteInputJson_ShemaWithRequiredParameters_NotValid(string json)
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(await Validator.Valid(json, schemaWithRequiredParameters));
        }

My Validator class:
        public static async Task<bool> Valid(string json, JSchema schema)
        {
            string schemaJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(schema);

            var jsonSchema = await NJsonSchema.JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(schemaJson);
            var errors = jsonSchema.Validate(json);
            foreach (var error in errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
            }

            if (errors.Count == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }

I thought there was a special parameter that would force the data type to be validated, but I didn’t find it. Thanks for your help and advice in advance

The problem turned out to be that I was writing the json schema into the Newtonsoft.Json JSchema object. For some reason I don't understand, when serializing a JSchema object into a string to pass the schema as a string to my validator object, since NJsonSchema accepted the schema as a string, it couldn't validate the object type correctly. I guess that this is because in the string format the data type was written for example: number, string, but in JScheme it saw object types as numbers (1, 2, etc.)
